# Computing reciprocal using intrinsics functions in C++

Tags: c++, intrinsics

I am trying to compute 1/x using intrinsic arithmetic and assuming that x is a double. I am trying to achieve the computation as follows:

```
__inline__ double __attribute__((const)) rcp_d (double x ) {
    double res;
    _mm_store_pd(&res,
                 _mm_rcp_ps(_mm_load_pd(&x))
        );

    return res;
}
```

But I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘__m128d {aka __vector(2) double}’ to ‘__m128 {aka __vector(4) float}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__m128 _mm_rcp_ps(__m128)’
                  _mm_rcp_ps(_mm_load_pd(&x))
```

Any suggestion in order to do the computation properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_mm_rcp_ps` works with the `__mm128` (4xfloat) data type, not doubles.  You should use `_mm_rcp14_pd` instead, although this instruction is only available on newer CPUs that support the AVX512 extensions.